# How to open a wepage that uses frameset to login with vba

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to open a webpage in order to login into a webpage but in IE I get The page cannot be displayed (I dont know if it is 404 error or not)

I think I have the proper link of the frame which includes username and password because it opens in Google Chrome

I Just created a variable with the link and did

```
.visible = true 
.Navigate url
```

How to open it with IE in order to pass username and password afterwards?

thank you

The main page has

```html
<FRAMESET rows="38,30,*"  border="0" frameborder="0"  framespacing="0">
<FRAME src="header.asp" name="header" id="header"  noresize  scrolling="no" border="0">
<FRAME src="empty.asp" name="menubar" id="menubar"   noresize  scrolling="no" border="0">
<FRAMESET cols="185, *" border="0" frameborder="0" framespacing="0">
  <FRAME src="left_column.asp" name="menu" id="menu" >
  <FRAME src="index.asp"  name="main" id="main" >
</FRAMESET>
```

Comment: So the page won't load at all in IE? Can you share the URL?

Comment: The initial page is http://shop.braintrust.gr/shop/store/index.html, I right clicked and inspect the username part and it shows a page of shop.braintrust.gr/shop/store/customerauthenticateform.asp which now is not opening neither with chrome and says to try and clean my cookies

Comment: may be a problem with website. I see Proxy Authentication Required and 302 indicating a re-direct.

Answer (score 0):

The site does a re-direct and using the /index can lead to too many indirects and ultimately failure. Go to the landing and then allow the browser to handle the initial re-direct to login. Then, yes, there is a frame to handle.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub LoginInfo()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate2 "http://shop.braintrust.gr/shop/store"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document.getElementById("main").contentDocument

            .querySelector("[name=UserID]") = "joe.bloggs@internet.address"
            .querySelector("[name=password]") = "password"
            .querySelector("#checkbox1").Click '< if checkbox needs checking
            .querySelector("[type=submit]").Click

        End With

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Stop
        '.Quit
    End With
End Sub
```